# Model I/O importing assets

Tags: swift3, gpu, .obj

I'm trying to use Model I/O as a quicker way to render imported 3d models for my iOS app. I have written a little bit of code importing and displaying a 3d model I have made with a .obj file format. For some reason, when I run my app only a black screen appears.Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import ModelIO
import SceneKit
import SceneKit.ModelIO

class ViewController: UIViewController {


var sceneView: SCNView {
    return self.view as! SCNView
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from                a nib.
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Digestive_System",      withExtension: "obj") else {
        fatalError("Failed to find model")

    }

    //Load Object
    let asset = MDLAsset(url:url)
    guard let object = asset.object(at: 0) as? MDLMesh else {
        fatalError("failed to get mesh from asset")
    }

    // Wrap Model I/O object in SceneKit object
    let scene = SCNScene()
    let node = SCNNode(mdlObject: object)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)


    //Display Scene

    sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
    sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
    sceneView.scene = scene
    sceneView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black








     super.viewDidLoad()
     }
```

side note: my model is located in the main folder of the app.

Thanks for your help guys!
Noa

Answer (score 0):

I have rendered .Obj model using Model I/O as:

1. Load model from bundle

   ```
   NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"modelName" withExtension:@"obj"];
   MDLAsset *asset = [[MDLAsset alloc] initWithURL:url];
   MDLMesh *meshObject = (MDLMesh *)[asset objectAtIndex:0];
   ```
2. Apply material to model

   ```
   MDLScatteringFunction *scattering = [MDLScatteringFunction new];
   MDLMaterial *mdMaterial = [[MDLMaterial alloc] initWithName:@"material" 
   scatteringFunction:scattering];

   NSURL *baseMaterialURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
   URLForResource:@"Image_Base_Color" withExtension:@"png"];
   MDLMaterialProperty *baseColor = [MDLMaterialProperty new];
   [baseColor setType:MDLMaterialPropertyTypeTexture];
   [baseColor setSemantic:MDLMaterialSemanticBaseColor];
   [baseColour setURLValue:baseMaterialURL];
   [material setProperty:baseColor];

    for(MDLSubmesh *subMesh in meshObject.submeshes)
    {
       sub.material = material;
    }
   ```
3. Add model to scene

   ```
    SCNNode *baseModelNode = [SCNNode nodeWithMDLObject:object];
    [self.sceneView.scene rootNode] addChildNode:self.baseModelNode];
   ```

You can set scale and position as per your requirement.